# Is it possible to protect API with these methods?

Tags: php, ajax, api, cross-domain

So far, i've tried to make something like:

1. Check users IP address and Host
2. If both match allowed Host & IP, allow access
3. If no, display error

I'm building API, and so far, all requests are coming from only my host. And here is the problem:

1. How to allow these requests be executed only if they are coming from local host (there are few that should only be executed by specified host, rest of methods should be available to public)
2. How to prevent people from spoofing referer and x-forwarded
3. Is it even possible?

**Here are some bits of code:**

**Set** *Access Origin Header*

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
        $refererProtocol = str_replace(':', '', substr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 0, strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], "/")));
        $refererHost = str_replace($refererProtocol . '://', '', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        $ACAO = $refererProtocol . '://' . substr($refererHost, 0, strpos($refererHost, "/"));
        $this->accessControl = [
            'allow_origin'  =>  $ACAO,
            'from_referer'  =>  true
        ];
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: " . $ACAO);
    } else {
        $this->accessControl = [
            'allow_origin'  =>  'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
            'from_referer'  =>  false
        ];
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: " . 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
    }
```

**Check** *Request Origin*

```
$localHost = 'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

    if ($this->accessControl['allow_origin'] === $localHost || $this->accessControl['allow_origin'] === $this->Settings['allow_host']) {
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
            $this->JSON->apiError(403, 'You are not allowed to execute this method', ['MyAPI', 'onlyLocalHost']);
            return false;
        } else {
            if ($this->Settings['allow_ip'] === $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) {
                return true;
            } else {
                $this->JSON->apiError(403, 'You are not allowed to execute this method', ['MyAPI', 'onlyLocalHost']);
                return false;
            }
        }
    } else {
        $this->JSON->apiError(403, 'You are not allowed to execute this method', ['MyAPI', 'onlyLocalHost']);
        return false;
    }
```

And everything could've been perfect, except one thing: im running CloudFlare and obviously i cannot check for **REMOTE_ADDR** anymore.

So, is there any possible solutions to this problem?

Comment: It will be better if you pass some token with your request to identify such host

Comment: @siddhesh, yep, already using it, but the problem is, people can still copy token and use it to bypass so called 'security'

Comment: you can make token time based means after specific time token will change say 15 min or 1day it will not the 100% solution but reduces the hack if somebody stills the token it will not valid after some time

Comment: anyway what do you mean by localhost from the 'same system where api resides'

Answer (score 2):

Cloudflare sent few variables

$_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"] To provide the client (visitor) IP address.

$_SERVER["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"] To provide country of visitor.

$_SERVER["HTTP_CF_VISITOR"] Show the scheme used to connect - HTTP or HTTPS.

$_SERVER["HTTP_CF_RAY"] The CF-Ray header is passed on which includes a hash appended with the datacenter the request came through.

Also you can use $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] This is a well-established HTTP header used by proxies, including CloudFlare, to pass along other IP addresses in the request.

More https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170986